# Delete something that is not in something in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two result sets, one is:

```
select * from tgCity
```

Which has about 850 records. It has `cityID` and `city name`.

The other result set is:

```
select max(cityID), city 
from tgCity 
group by City
```

This returns about 700 records. The reason is that in the 850 there are 150 duplicated records of some cities inside the 700 records.

How can I write a script to delete in the `tgCity` table that only deletes those 150 records?

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I said, MSSQL is that the reason you -1?

Comment: . . I don't downvote, so that wouldn't be me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another classic solution using a `WHERE EXISTS` condition :

```
DELETE t
FROM tgCity t
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM tgCity t1 WHERE t1.city = t.city AND t1.cityId < t.cityId
)
```

This will delete records having the same `city` while keeping the one with the smallest `cityId` in the group.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=96fa4e9d2ad868ba783617ea0b6948bc)**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `CityId` is unique, a common method is:

```
delete from tgCity tg
    where tg.cityId < (select tg2.cityId
                       from tgCity tg2
                       where tg2.city = tg.city
                      );
```

Comment: SOrry, where is tg2 coming from?

Comment: @ZechengLi . . . It is a table alias.

Answer (score 0):

This script deletes duplicate cities:

```
Delete c2 from tgCity c1 join tgCity c2
On c1.city=c2.city
Where c2.city_id>c1.city_id
```